# Divide Values in Chart in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I try to create in SSRS a report.

[image]

[image]

This shows me the piece of numbers. And I wish to see the percentage. I must divide to get the percentage of these Countername with the Produced pieces. And this produced pieces is in the same table like the other conter names.

My Query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select  
        tsystem.Name as Name, 
        CounterName,
        calculationUnitsInitial,
        Sum(case when CounterName = 'Produziert' then calculationUnitsInitial else 0 end) as Produced

from IntervalCount inner join tsystem ON IntervalCount.systemid = tsystem.id
    where IntervalDate >= @StartDate And IntervalDate <= @EndDate 
    and  tsystem.ID in  (Select SystemID from tSystemViewSystem where SystemViewID in ('2', '3', '4', '5'))     
    and tsystem.Name = @Maschine    
    and CounterName in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
    group by tsystem.Name, OeeCounterName, calculationUnitsInitial 
    ) as s
```

And If I divide the countername with produced:

```
=iif(Fields!calculationUnitsInitial.Value=0 OR Fields!Produced.Value=0,0, Sum(Fields!calculationUnitsInitial.Value)/Sum(Fields!Produced.Value)*100)
```

This not show me no bar in my chart:
[image]

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, What is the purpose of this `IIF` statement? Why not just suppress 0's in your SQL?

```
iif(Fields!calculationUnitsInitial.Value=0 OR Fields!ProduzierteTampons.Value=0,0,
```

Try changing this, then doing the following below:

In the Horizontal Axis Properties, you should be able to change the Format of the number displayed under Number -> Percentage.

Click OK and see if this gives you your desired result.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this is not the solution. I tried it but the chart not shows any bar

Comment: The purpose of this `iif` statement is, that in `calculationUnitsInitial` there are 0 values, If I don´t use this `iif ` statement then the chart shows me an error because I cannot divide through 0

Comment: Your pictures show you viewing two different "Maschine". Is this done on purpose? When you search both in SQL, do you get the same results? I would try to test this more in SQL Sever or whatever tool you're using. It seems that you're data is pulling 0 rows for the bottom one which means your result set is most likely 0 rows due to whatever `Fields!XYZ.value = 0` is

Comment: If I choose the same machine the result is the same like in the last picture.

Comment: Again, I suggest testing your sql first, suppress the rows you do not want to see, then return to SSRS after you're confident your code will work in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Quick suggestion ... try to revise your iif statement

```
=iif(Fields!calculationUnitsInitial.Value=0 OR Fields!ProduzierteTampons.Value=0,0, 100.0* (Sum(Fields!calculationUnitsInitial.Value)/Sum(Fields!ProduzierteTampons.Value))
```

Perhaps the order of the divide and multiply is giving you a very small number close to zero.